# Use of the term "reckon"

Tags: etymology

Did the use of the term *I reckon* originate in the UK or in the southern US?  I hear the term being used both in British English (like on the BBC) as well as in southern US dialect.

Comment: It comes from the [Old English word *gerecenian*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=reckon&searchmode=none), meaning "to explain, relate, recount." So England.

Comment: Note that there are two fairly distinct (but related) meanings/uses (in the US).  Reckon meaning to "calculate" (as in "dead reckoning") is a fairly "normal" word (though typically only used in limited circumstances).  Reckon meaning to "believe" ("Well, I reckon he's about to Omaha by now") is not as formal/"normal", and is often used (in movies, etc) to suggest a "country" dialect.

Comment: In Britain there is no correlation between using the word "reckon" and lack of education or intelligence, as there seems to in the States.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to be completely certain what you are asking, because the verb *reckon* can be used in many ways, all of them with a subject in the first person singular. It looks to me that this wasn’t something you reckoned with, unfortunately.

But the one you’re thinking of, I imagine, is the one that could replace the first instance of *imagine* in this sentence.  The OED says that this is used parenthetically or finally, and that

> > Formerly in literary Eng. use; still common in Eng. dialects, and current in the southern States of America in place of the northern *I guess*.

So it certainly began in England where it saw literary use, and is still common there in various dialects as well as a distinctively Dixie thing in the States.

The first citation for this sense antedates Plymouth Rock:

> - **1603** Sir R. Cecil in Harington *Nugæ Ant*. (1804) I. 345 ― He is, I reckon, no wise man that looketh this waye to heaven.

However, it is also possible that you’re thinking of this very slightly more general sense:

> To consider, think, suppose, be of opinion, etc., *that*. Also with omission of *that*. Now usu. *colloq*., esp. in the U.S. (formerly chiefly in southern States).

The first citation is from the early 1500s, and two centuries after that Jonathan Swift was using it in the modern way when in 1712 [he wrote](https://goo.gl/v9OzMa):

> I reckon the Queen will go to Windsor in three or four weeks: and if the Secretary takes a house there, I shall be sometimes with him.

Here are two recent citations of the same use:

> - **1963** *Social Problems* Spring 367/1, ― I reckon it’ll always be lucky.
> - **1977** I. Shaw *Beggarman, Thief* ɪɪɪ. ii. 193, ― I don’t reckon I’ve had a fare there for more than ten years.

Perhaps these are not the senses you were looking for, but if you would be so kind as to elaborate your intended sense, you can reckon on further OED citations for that one, too.

Comment: Nice bit of reconnoitering through the multitude of available historical sources.

Answer (score -1):

"I reckon" and ".. didn't reckon on" are common in different area of England. There were certainly common in northern English accents in my grandparent's time -  well before TV or other media would have brought any American influence

Answer (score -1):

The word *reckon* is often used in place of *guess* or *think*.

Typically, a common American English stereotype is that it signifies ignorance or a lack of intelligence and is commonly used when creating “southern” or “western” dialogue.

However, though the word’s usage is scarce nowadays, it is still used when creating dialectical differences due to its strong relation to those who are of the aforementioned regions.